# Altes Wort für ‚alleinerziehend‘/‚Single‘

Tags: single-word-request, history

Unabhängig davon, ob oder wie sehr es gesellschaftlich geächtet war, hat es in der Vergangenheit immer auch alleinstehende Mütter gegeben, die nicht verwitwet waren. Gab es für sie eine mglw. abschätzige oder regionale Bezeichnung?

Für Frauen, die außereheliche Beziehungen zu Männern hatten, gab es schließlich diverse Begriffe (*Konkubine, Mätresse*) und auch für die so gezeugten Kinder (*Kegel*).

Comment: _Alte Jungfer_ trifft es jedenfalls nicht, weil die tendenziell kinderlos ist.

Comment: aber oft nicht wirklich jungfräulich

Comment: Ich frage mich, ob ein separater Begriff wirklich nötig war, oder ob die Zahl der unverheirateten Frauen, die es wagten ein Kind allein groß zu ziehen, einfach zu gering war. Vielleicht kann man mal bei History.SE nachfragen, ob es zur Anzahl/Rate der alleinerziehenden nicht-verwitweten gesicherte Daten gibt... Spannende Frage jedenfalls :)

Answer (score 4):

*Schandmutter* war im Mittelalter und der frühen Neuzeit ein gängiger Begriff, der sich auch bei Google Books in alten [Büchern](https://books.google.de/books?id=JxBYAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA6&dq=schandmutter&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjAuu-10uTZAhWmhaYKHU_kBN4Q6AEIKDAA#v=onepage&q=schandmutter&f=false) finden lässt.

Für die unehelichen Kinder bitte den *Bankert* nicht vergessen

Comment: Sind Schandmütter notwendigerweise alleinerziehend? Vgl. Rabenmutter.

Comment: @Pollitzer Nicht *absolut notwendigerweise*, aber *ziemlich notwendigerweise*, weil sich keiner mehr mit ihnen eingelassen hat, weil er keinen Ärger mit seinem Pfarrer uns dessen oberstem Chef haben wollte..

Answer (score 2):

Da müsste man in entsprechenden Romanen lesen. Mir fiele der Begriff 'gefallenes Mädchen' ein, ich weiß aber nicht, ob sich das nicht nur auf die 'verlorene Unschuld' (außereheliche und ruchbar gewordene Defloration) bezieht. Es gibt dazu auch Literatur, z.B.: Single Moms. Alleinstehende Mütter und ihre Lebenswelten. Ausstellungskatalog Band 1, hrsg. von Bettina Bab und Marianne Pitzen. Bonn, April 2014. ISBN Nr. 978-3-940482-74-7. Dieser Hinweis stammt von folgender Seite:

https://mama-arbeitet.de/familie/alleinerziehende-stigma-geschichte

Ganz interessant, was da zu lesen ist. Es scheint so zu sein, dass die Tatsache einer Mutterschaft ohne Ehe in früheren Zeiten automatisch mit einem liederlichen Lebenswandel der betroffenen Frau gleichgesetzt wurde, daher die vielen entsprechenden Vorschläge hierzugroup. Wer als Frau das Pech hatte, mit einem Kind sitzengelassen zu werden, war wohl ziemlich übel dran und konnte von Glück reden, wenn er nicht von Familie oder Dorfgemeinschaft verstoßen wurde. Für die Kinder galt Entsprechendes. Ist wohl noch nicht so ganz schrecklich lange her, dass in die Klassenbücher auch der Beruf des Vaters eingetragen wurde, da standen die Kinder ohne Väter ziemlich dumm da.

Comment: "Gefallenes Mädchen" ist bombig und ergänzt das, was ich gechrieben habe in die jüngere Vergangenheit. Allerdings keine Referenz auf die Mutterschaft, sondern "nur" auf die bekannt gewordene uneheliche Beziehung.

Answer (score 1):

Gleich vorweg: Außer *»ledige Mutter«* kenne ich dafür keinen Begriff, aber ich kenne zwei Wörter, die etwas ähnliches bedeuten:

---

**Dirn**

Die **Dirn** war zumindest im Süden des deutschen Sprachraums ursprünglich nichts weiter als ein weibliches Kind oder eine unverheiratete junge Frau (mit oder ohne Nachwuchs), die allerdings aus einer der unteren gesellschaftlichen Schichten kam.

In dem Kinderlied »Spannenlanger Hansl« kommt die Dirn noch in dieser Bedeutung vor:

> Spannenlanger Hansl, nudeldicke **Dirn,**
>   gemma<sup>*</sup> in den Garten, schütteln wir die Birn’.
>   Schüttel ich die großen, schüttelst du die kleinen,
>   wenn das Sackerl voll ist, gehn wir wieder heim.

<sup>* (*»gemma« = »gehen wir«)*</sup>

Und auch im Märchen »Rotkäppchen« wird die Titelheldin gleich im ersten Satz als *Dirn* bezeichnet:

> Es war einmal eine kleine süße **Dirn,** die hatte jedermann lieb.

Als Diminutiv *»Dirndl«* (*kleine Dirn*) wird dieses Wort auch heute noch in vielen ländlichen Gegenden Österreichs genau in dieser Bedeutung verwendet. Sowohl das *»Dirndl«* als auch das *»Mädl«* (*kleine Maid = Mädchen*) bezeichnen hier weibliche Personen im Kindesalter bis zum jungen Erwachsenenalter, wobei das *Mädl* eher Kinder und das *Dirndl* eher junge Frauen bezeichnet.
(Das, was man im gesamten deutschen Sprachraum sonst als *»Dirndl«* kennt, ist eigentlich das *»Dirndlkleid«*, also das Kleid eines Dirndls, wobei dieses Kleid auch von verheirateten Frauen getragen wird.)

Die Wörter *»Dirn«* und *»Maid«* hatten mal ziemlich dieselbe Bedeutung. Während aber die *Maid* zur *Magd* wurde und so erst die Bedeutung *»weiblicher Knecht«* annahm und dann ganz verschwand (und nur ihren Diminutiv *Mädchen* im deutschen Wortschatz zurückließ), wurde aus der *»Dirn«* die *»Dirn**e**«*, die heute eigentlich nur noch als Synonym für *»Prostituierte«* verwendet wird.

---

**Flietscherl, Flietschn**

Das leichte Mädchen wird seit dem 19. Jahrhundert (wie ich vermute aber ebenfalls nur im Süden des deutschen Sprachraums) abwertend als *»Flietscherl«* bezeichnet, wobei damit aber meist gar nicht gemeint ist, dass die der Prostitution nachging, sondern nur, dass sie leicht zu haben war und häufig ihre Partner wechselte. Wer besonders gehässig sein wollte, verzichtete auf die Verniedlichungsform und sprach von einer *»Flietschn«*.

Comment: *Das Flittchen* ist auch im Hochdeutschen bekannt.

Comment: Stimmt, daran habe ich gar nicht gedacht. *Flietscherl* und *Flittchen* sind ja verwandt miteinander. Allerdings ist mir das Wort nur als Diminutiv bekannt, Von einer *»Flitte«* habe ich noch nie gehört.

Comment: Das ist analog *Liebchen* aus dem Verb *flittern* gebildert, denke ich.

Comment: _Dirn_ oder _Deern_ für 'Mädchen' gibt es auch in norddeutschen Dialekten immer noch, ebenso diverse Bezeichnungen für Huren und Flittchen, aber so eine richtige Antwort auf meine Frage ist das leider nicht. Natürlich ist "nein, gibt es nicht" schwieriger zu belegen als "js, und zwar: ...".

Comment: *Metze* oder *Mätze* war ein ähnlicher Begriff wie *Dirne*, den es aber heute überhaupt nicht mehr gibt.

Comment: Auch bei dieser Antwort ist das *Mutter sein* kein Bestandteil der genannten Begriffe.

Comment: @tofro: Die *Metze* war aber auch ein Teil des Zuggeschirrs von Pferden und sie war auch ein Hohlmaß (ca. 20 Liter). Darüber hinaus war es auch eine Verniedlichungsform der Vornamens *Mechthild* und *Mathilde*. Ich kannte die Metze zuvor auch nur als Synonym für *Dirne,* aber als ich vor wenigen Monaten auf den [Metzenhof](https://www.metzenhof.at/) stieß, habe ich mal recherchiert und bin auf den entsprechenden Eintrag bei [Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metze/) gestoßen.

Answer (score -1):

Als abwertende Bezeichnung für eine Alleinerziehende fällt mir zumindest

> die Verlassene

ein, vielleicht noch

> die Verschmähte

Spezifisch alt sind diese Ausdrücke natürlich nicht, außerdem auch auf eine Kinderlose anwendbar. Frauen ohne Kinder waren früher allerdings selten, schon allein, weil nicht verhütet wurde.

[*Bild zur Antwort*](https://www.flickr.com/photos/rockhopper99/2810845842/in/photostream/)

Comment: Beide Begriffe implizieren in keinster Weise, dass da Nachwuchs im Spiel ist.

Comment: @tofro: Muss nicht, aber kann.

Comment: Man könnte es erweitern um "verschmähte Mutter". Das klingt autentisch, jedoch fürchte ich, es war nicht wirklich in Gebrauch... oder jedenfalls müsste der Nachweis erst erbracht werden.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann Klingt für mich nicht authentisch - Nach den damaligen Moralvorstellungen waren Frauen, die sich vor der Ehe mit Männern eingelassen haben, Schlampen. *Verschmäht* klingt nicht sehr danach.